# How can I determine that the value of column1 in df1 contains in column1 in df2 (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have df1 [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NRL5.png)
and
have df2 [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVGtC.png)

My question how is it possible to determine if `df1['whitelist']` contains `df2[blocked]`.

Desirable result:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56UUU.png)

I was trying:

```
df2['white_list_num']=df2.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['blocked'] in df1['whitelist'] else 'no num',axis=1)

df1['yes/no'] = [df1["whitelist"].str.find(i) for i in df2['blocked'].to_list()]
df1
```

but they don't work

Desirable result:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56UUU.png)

Comment: So, you want to know if any part of a df2 entry is found in df1?  At any location or only at the start?

Comment: If df2 in any location of df1

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking. Your expected output image shows both dataframes joined by index; but you want to find if column of a dataframe exists in another. Please edit your question and restate your problem. **Please provide your dataset as text - not as image**. Refer [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding and your desired output, you want to check if `whitelist` contains `blocked` even if it is partially containing it. This can be used:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'whitelist': [1567891112, 1781305891, 2358911121]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'blocked': [156789111, 178130, 23589]})

# checking if whitelist contains blocked values even partially and if so, replacing them with the full whitelist value
df2['whitelist'] = df2['blocked'].apply(lambda x: df1['whitelist'][df1['whitelist'].astype(str).str.contains(str(x))].values[0] if len(df1['whitelist'][df1['whitelist'].astype(str).str.contains(str(x))].values) > 0 else x)
```

**Output:**

```
     blocked   whitelist
0  156789111  1567891112
1     178130  1781305891
2      23589  2358911121
```

Works well even on smaller partial values.